# Spacy sentence segmentation by using custom rule unable to get required output

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

```
document = nlp('I am Roshan.*.I am worried.*.Future!')
for sent in document.sents:
    print(sent)
```

I am Roshan.*.I am worried.*.Future!

```
def rule(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text =='.*.':
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start==True
    return doc

nlp.remove_pipe('rule')
nlp.add_pipe(rule,before='parser')
rule(document)
for sent in document.sents:
    print(sent)
```

I am Roshan.*.I am worried.*.Future!

I want each sentence which should be ended before `.*.` give me a proper solution to my problem, please because I not get that type sentence segmentation.

Comment: What could be a reason for asking questions and not accepting *any* answer? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you

> want each sentence which should be ended before `.*.`

then try:

1. changing tokenization rules with `nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer`
2. filter out unwanted token `.*.`

```py
import spacy
from spacy.util import compile_infix_regex

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
regex = (r'\.\*\.',) + nlp.Defaults.infixes
infix_re = compile_infix_regex(regex)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_re.finditer

document = nlp('I am Roshan.*.I am worried.*.Future!')
for sent in document.sents:
    l = len([tok for tok in sent if tok.text != ".*."])
    print(sent[:l])
I am Roshan
I am worried
Future!
```